# Expected a declaration (compiler error C2059)

Tags: c++, syntax

The following is giving me a compiler error:

```
#include <foo.h>

#define ODP ( \

    L"bar. " \ // C2059 here

    L"baz.")

#define FFW (5)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In addition to the syntactic errors already listed, what are you trying to do?  I don't know what you want to do, and without knowing that it's really not possible to tell you how to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot the line splice characters

```
#define ODP ( \
              \
    L"bar. "  \
              \
    L"baz.")
```

Not sure why you put those newlines though. It all gets down to

```
#define ODP (L"bar. baz.")
```

Note that the characters must be the last ones on the line. And you cannot put a line comment (`//`) *before* them, because the line comment would extend to the next physical line. Use C Style comments if you still want to comment the lines separately

```
#define ODP (         \
    /* this is bar */ \
    L"bar. "          \
    /* this is baz */ \
    L"baz.")
```

Answer (score 2):

Other than the blank lines that are obvious, the hard one is the one you cannot see.  A space or a tab after the backslash also produces this compile error.